# Автоматический редирект дублей страниц либо на .htaccess либо на PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

Добрый день! Проблема достаточна частая, так как в `URL` файла можно дописывать кучу всякого мусора по типу `?и_так_далее_что_хочешь_и_сколько` или `#это вообще трэш: тут можно все что угодно в URL писать` и наконец-то самый ужасный `/и_тут_тоже`, даже если это файл а не директория.

Задача: **Перенаправлять пользователя на оригинал если он написал `?` или `/` после URL**.

Примеры:

№1: `/en/`– главная, но можно попасть на ту же страницу написав такое: `/en//` или больше слэшев в конце.

№2: директория `/en/register/register.php` и если после `.php` дописать слэш и потом все что угодно, то откроется та же страница.

Comment: ...эммм....што?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Чет самому смешно стало :D

Comment: Просмеявшись, надеюсь, вы переформулируете свой вопрос?

Comment: @vp_arth Да сейчас :D

Comment: я все пропустил, или это еще оригинал вопроса? 8)

Comment: Возможно, что-то вроде? `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] !== $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) {header("Location: {$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}"); exit();}`

Comment: @vp_arth В том то и дело, что `PHP_SELF` и `REQUEST_URI` равны, и они динамические.

Comment: а вообще зачем такое нужно? если юзер умышленно вбивает ненужные символы — сам дурак. А неумышленно - это надо через коленку как-то извернуться, чтоб так сделать

Comment: @teran Это уже не оригинал. Там я написал такой трэш. что сам угарал.